# c++ Map cache not find entrys

Tags: c++, dictionary, search

Im trying to write a cached shader storage, currently im using a Map in a Map, the first map holds the pair. map_of_uniformlocations holds . With my current solution it will always go to the else statement and instead of getting the data from the map, i think this is because im inserting a new map of map_of_uniformlocations each time when i should just be updating it but now im stuck on how to do that. any pointers would be appreciated

```
        uniformCache = m_UniformCache[shaderID];

        //if specified shader uniform can be found
        auto uniformLocation = uniformCache.find(name);
        if (uniformLocation != uniformCache.end())
        {
                            //this is true for only one of the objects in the map
            return uniformLocation->second;
        }
        else
        {
            unsigned int uniformGetLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, name.c_str());
            if (uniformGetLocation == -1)
            {
                return -1;
            }
           //I think the problem is with this
            uniformCache.insert(std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>(name, uniformGetLocation));
            m_UniformCache.insert(std::pair<unsigned int, std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int>>(shaderID, uniformCache));

            return uniformGetLocation;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `uniformCache = m_UniformCache[shaderID];` is not inserting a new element to the map? Better use `std::map::at()`.

Comment: changed it to that and it still happens

Answer (score 0):

### Use a single Map

Perhaps not the answer you were looking for, but instead of using 2 maps, you should be able to use just a single map for this problem.

While it's certainly possible using a map of maps, using just one map will help to avoid a lot of pitfalls and errors.

Defining a map using a `std::tuple` yields a map that has a compound key.

Define the map then as follows:

```
using UniformLocationCacheMap = std::map< std::tuple<std::string, int>, UniformLocation>;
```